# python code to change the desktop background gives a black screen

Tags: python-3.x

I have looked at other questions but they still don't solve this. both these python codes bellow just give a black screen. what am I doing wrong.

```
import ctypes
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 2
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 1
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE, "C:\\Users\Jason\Documents\Python and stuff\Image.bmp" , SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
```

and

```
import ctypes
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "C:\\Users\Jason\Documents\Python and stuff\Image.bmp" , 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is in your link. There are two problems:

1. "\" is an escape character. So to actually write a single backslash, you need to have a double blackslash.
2. You have "C:\", but the actual link needs "C:\". But that part is right because the double backslash is a code for a single one.

Here is the line, if I'm not being very clear:
"C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Python and stuff\Image.bmp"

Comment: C:\Users will give a Unicode error because \U is a command. I have tried links such as F:\Image.bmp but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't worked out the answer by now you can use this:

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui, random, time

def SetWallPaper(path):
    key = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(win32con.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                                "Control Panel\\\\Desktop",
                                0,win32con.KEY_SET_VALUE)
    win32api.RegSetValueEx(key, "WallpaperStyle", 0, win32con.REG_SZ, "0")
    win32api.RegSetValueEx(key, "TileWallpaper", 0, win32con.REG_SZ, "0")
    win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, path, 1+2)

path = r"C:\\Users\Jason\Documents\Python and stuff\Image.bmp"
SetWallPaper(path)
```

If you put an r at the start of the file path python wont treat the `\` as an escape character and just leave it as it is. You are getting the black screen because according to python your path doesn't exist. Alternitively if you dont like the `r` method then you can just double slash `\\`

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Quite Late, Arent I?
Well, anyways, this code should work!

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32con

def wallpaper(path):
    key = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(win32con.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Control Panel\\Desktop",0,win32con.KEY_SET_VALUE)
    win32api.RegSetValueEx(key, "WallpaperStyle", 0, win32con.REG_SZ, "0")
    win32api.RegSetValueEx(key, "TileWallpaper", 0, win32con.REG_SZ, "0")
    win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, path, 1+2)

wallpaper('C:\\Users\\Jason\\Documents\\Python and stuff\\Image.bmp')
```

Comment: Can you go a small step further and explain why this code should work, please?

Comment: TBH, I don't really know, But as I can understand, it goes to 'Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop' in the windows registry, and then edits the 'WallpaperStyle' data, and then changes the 'WallPaper' data to the path that you input